# Render Bootstrap dropdown menu with c# html dropdown list helper

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-helper

I have created a search input for my website that is attached to a dropdown menu. But I need to populate the items in the dropdown menu with items from a html helper select list which is essential for the search function. Is it possible to render the items of the search list in a bootstrap dropdown menu that is posted to a controller?

**HTML Search Function**

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
@{using (Html.BeginForm("Results", "Searchv2", FormMethod.Get)) {
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      @Html.DropDownList("Searchby", new SelectList(new[] { "User", "Restaurant", "Cuisine" }))
      </ul>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="SearchString" id="SearchString">
  </div>
}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the conventional hyperlink tags in the bootstrap dropdown-menu:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
@foreach (var searchType in new[] { "User", "Restaurant", "Cuisine" })
{
    <li><a href="#">@searchType</a></li>
}
</ul>
```

Then use JQuery to set a hidden input value when these hyperlinks are selected:

```
<input type="hidden" name="SearchBy" />
<script>
    $(".dropdown-menu a").click(function() {        
        $("input[name='SearchBy']").val($(this).html());            
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This renders the in the select list in the drop down menu. But it doesn't pass the value of searchBy into the controller. How would I do this?

Comment: Do you see the value being passing in the Url when you click submit? You can access by adding a string parameter called SearchBy to the controller method. You can also simply use Request.QueryString["SearchBy"]